# Multiple buttons to link to different page and different query

Tags: navigation, routes, theming

I have a page in my site (from a custom module) with a hook_menu (red boxes).

[image]

The code for the menu is as follows:

```
$items['upcoming_games/' . date('Y-m-d')] = array(
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  'title' => 'Upcoming Games',
  'page callback' => 'my_page',
  'access callback' => TRUE
);
```

The page callback calls a function where I insert the date as an argument for a query.
When clicking the menu, it defaults to TODAY.

What I need is to query for a different date depending on the click of the coloured buttons. I get "page not found"...

In the function where I have my query I get the date with the follwing code:

```
$date_to_show = arg(1);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
function sample_menu() {
  // This is a default option, without argument.
  $items['upcoming_games'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upcoming Games',
    'page callback' => 'my_page',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  // This is for any other date.
  $items['upcoming_games/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upcoming Games',
    'page callback' => 'my_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_page($date = NULL) {
  // If the $date has not been defined, it means that the user is trying to see
  // today's games.
  if (!$date) {
    // Redirect to today's date.
    drupal_goto('upcoming_games/' . format_date(REQUEST_TIME, 'custom', 'Y-m-d'));
  }
  // Otherwise, check the date. The strtotime() function is just as an example.
  else {
    $date = strtotime($date);
  }
  // Continue the operation.
  // ...
  return 'Upcoming games for ' . format_date($date, 'custom', 'Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Topsitemakers! I made the change and the url now works with the argument but I lost the menu from the main menu. I need it to be there and to default to the present day. Also, to prevent the user from writing invalid/not allowed dates, I have to make that logic in the my_page function, right?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the default functionality. Regarding the date logic - yes, you will have to implement that yourself. You could use the `strtotime()` function, which will convert the date string / digits into a UNIX timestamp. I added that as well as an example.

Comment: Almost there. When clicking the default menu, without argument, the url is just /upcoming_games. It should be /upcoming_games/2015-04-18 (for today). Also, in every url I'm getting an error => Notice: Undefined index: localized_options in menu_navigation_links() (line 1863 of /home/.../public_html/.../includes/menu.inc).

Comment: Answer updated; typos fixed as well.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped.